# What is the setAllowUserInteraction() in HttpConnection

Tags: android, http, httpconnection

How this method `setAllowUserInteraction()` in `HttpConnection` works internally?
**What is the meaning of user interaction in this case ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is supposed to indicate that if required the system can ask the user for additional input (for example: if used in an applet and a URL request is made that requires a username/password this signifies that the system GUI to ask the user for input can be called).